# Why does JPEG show at half size in Adobe Bridge on Retina display?

Tags: adobe-bridge

I'm still setting up my MBP Retina, but noticed this weird thing. Raw photos work fine, but JPEGs show at half size in Adobe Bridge. If they are 1024 px wide they are shown at 512 px. I can't seem to find a setting for this, might it be a bug?

Tried at different display resolution scalings. Using Bridge CC (6.0.1.6).

This first screenshot is on my 24" 1920x1200 monitor.

[image]

This second is on my laptop retina screen.

[image]

Comment: did you shoot in jpeg? or are you talking about jpegs embedded in raws? in the latter case, the jpegs inside are half resolution if you are using canon.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen No I mean any JPEG file. I could create a 100x100 blank JPEG in Photoshop and it would show as 50x50 in Bridge (measured in a screenshot).

Comment: @Znarkus Do you mean Bridge actually says under the file that it is 50x50 pixels, or do you mean that they just _look_ smaller in Bridge? Maybe a few screen dumps could help us understand better.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. However,  the post is asking about RAW vs JPG, but the screenshots show PNG's but on different screens, right? What I see in the screenshots is natural, since a retina screen has double pixel density, hence the photo is displayed at a quarter physical size. 

If it's the case that the Retina Mac displays JPGs and RAWs of the same pixel count at different physical sizes on the screen (and zoom level isn't a factor), then that could be considered a bug. Could you post screenshots of that (if that's the issue at hand)?

Comment: The raw file was probably high res and the jpeg 1024 px. As I said in the question, I don't want the 1024 px image to be displayed at 512 px..

Comment: Well, thats the nature of a retina screen. It displays 4 pixels in the same physical area a non-retina would display 1. The whole point of retina is the increased pixel density, right? If you want a picture displayed over a larger physical area you would have to zoom.

Answer (score 1):

The first screenshot has a resolution of 899 × 650 px. The second screenshot has a resolution of 1798 × 1300 px, which is exactly twice the resolution in both dimensions.

A 100% zoom of *both* screenshots will show the 2nd screenshot to appear twice as large (dimensionally), and the "Preview" areas will be identically sized.